# How can retrieve the value of a non-standard keyword attribute using regex to match attribute's value with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

In a private project (learning python scripting), i needed to retrieve only the rpm package of the scrapped page. I spotted that all package links (.msi, .deb, .rpm) has an attribute called data-link inside 'a' balise.

I also taylored my own regex (https://regexr.com/6rqd2) to match only the package i need.

According to documentation, it seems that this kind of attribute (data-*) is a non-standard
attribute in HTML 5.

So i tried the attrs argument and passed into find_all() but with no success.

Unsuccessfull Code below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.splunk.com/en_us/download/splunk-enterprise.html"


page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

pattern = re.compile("(?<=data-link=\")[^ ]+rpm")


package = soup.find_all(attrs={"data-link": pattern})

print(package)
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, using CSS selectors:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.splunk.com/en_us/download/splunk-enterprise.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select('a[data-link$=".rpm"]'):
    print(a["data-link"])
```

Prints:

```
https://download.splunk.com/products/splunk/releases/9.0.0.1/linux/splunk-9.0.0.1-9e907cedecb1-linux-2.6-x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: It worked with css selectors.
Flawless solution. Thanks.

I tried to understand and play a bit with your soup.select. But the construction of the arguments passed to soups.select remains obscure according to my level of knowledge of python.
Specially 'a[data-link$=".rpm"]' and why and how '$' sign is there when in regex it specifies an EOL.
I'm interested if you have documentation on it.

Comment: @VenomCA Good starter documentation on CSS Selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp  `a[data-link$=".rpm"]` means "give" me all `<a>` tags where `data-link=` attribute ends with `.rpm`

Answer (score 1):

Do you need all the features beautiful soup provides? The below should find the links as required.

```py
re.findall(pattern, str(page.content))
```

Comment: No i'aint need all feature but i let you know that your solution was close to be the most flawless. The only inconvenience is that it returns the link with Bracket and quotes. I would have prefered naked link. Do you think we can improve your proposition towards this way? Anyway, the formula is usefull by its simplicity. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include `data-link` in your expression because you're searching by a value of the attribute, so you're matching a value only, not a full element:

```py
soup.find_all(
    "a",
    {"data-link": re.compile(r"^(.+?)\.rpm$")},
)
```

Comment: thank you but your solution retrieve all the balise with all element and their value.

Comment: if you want only one element just replace `find_all` with `find` and if you want to extract the `data-link` specifically just access its ["data-link"] key: `result = soup.find("a", {"data-link": re.compile(r"^(.+?)\.rpm$")}) print(result["data-link"])` Outputs `https://download.splunk.com/products/splunk/releases/9.0.0.1/linux/splunk-9.0.0.1-9e907cedecb1-linux-2.6-x86_64.rpm`